# Resources for understanding statistical mathematics behind metaheuristic algorithms

Tags: probability, optimization

I am working on an engineering problem and I am going to use a novel modified metaheuristic algorithms to solve that problem. Something is completely confusing for me about metaheuristic algorithms and that is statistical mathematics behind them. Every course and book which I have used, just describe the methods and does not statistical mathematics. It is clear! They just want to tell about the basics and applications. It'd be great if you can recommend some courses or books or research papers ,which can help me to fulfill my knowledge about metaheuristic methods.
Not bad to say that I have already passed engineering statistics in university but I have not passed statistical process yet.

Comment: You might get a better response asking this question on the Math Educators stackexchange.

Comment: The important thing to understand about metaheuristics is that most of them are garbage.

Comment: thank you guys, you know! we are inevitably forced to use them in complex problems in engineering. in my case: GA , WOA, CS , ALO , ...